# Ant Design Table component not displaying state-based dataSource change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using Ant Design for my React project and I'm having trouble with the Table component. I have a list of tasks to which I add a new task based on a Form content - currently just by adding to an array of objects (`taskListMock` in the code snippets), the app is not linked to any backend. The form works fine, however, the Table does not refresh, even though the `dataSource` prop of the Table gets its content directly from the state and the state updates correctly - confirmed by logging and devtools. Curiously, the table refreshes with the new task when I initiate the implemented sorting, so my suspicion is that the Table somehow does not refresh its content from the state change, only on `onChange` hooks or something, but I'm feeling in a bit of a dead-end - any help would be greatly appreciated since I'm planning to use similar functionality in other Tables.

The structure is pretty simple, I have a TasksIndex.js with the Table as an individual component in TaskListTable.js

TaskListTable.js:

```
const TaskListTable = (props) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  const [tableContent, setTableContent] = useState(props.tasks);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Table
        pagination={false}
        dataSource={tableContent}
        columns={[
          {
            title: t("tasks.name"),

            key: "name",
            render: (text) => {
              return <p>{text.slug}</p>;
            },
          },
          {
            title: t("tasks.dateDue"),
            dataIndex: "dateDue",
            key: "dateDue",
            sorter: (a, b) =>
              new Date(a.dateDue).getTime() - new Date(b.dateDue).getTime(),
            render: (dateDue) => {
              let dateFormatted = moment(dateDue);
              return <>{dateFormatted.format("LL")}</>;
            },
            defaultSortOrder: "ascend",
          },
          {
            title: t("tasks.priority"),
            key: "priority",
            dataIndex: "priority",
            render: (priority) => (
              <React.Fragment>
                {priority === "low" ? (
                  <Tag color="geekblue">{t("tasks.lowPriority")}</Tag>
                ) : (
                  ""
                )}
                {priority === "normal" ? (
                  <Tag color="green">{t("tasks.normalPriority")}</Tag>
                ) : (
                  ""
                )}
                {priority === "high" ? (
                  <Tag color="volcano">{t("tasks.highPriority")}</Tag>
                ) : (
                  ""
                )}
              </React.Fragment>
            ),
            sorter: (a, b) => {
              const priorityOrder = ["low", "normal", "high"];

              return (
                priorityOrder.indexOf(a.priority) -
                priorityOrder.indexOf(b.priority)
              );
            },
          },
          {
            title: t("tasks.options"),
            key: "options",
            render: (item) => {
              return (
                <Checkbox value={item.id}>{t("tasks.setCompleted")}</Checkbox>
              );
            },
          },
        ]}
      ></Table>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default TaskListTable;
```

TaskIndex.js:

```
const TasksIndex = () => {
  const [isModalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const [taskList, updateTaskList] = useState(taskListMock);

  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  const addTask = useCallback(
    (values) => {
      const newTaskList = taskList;

      newTaskList.push({
        id: taskList[taskList.length - 1] + 1,
        slug: values.name,
        description: values.description,
        dateDue: values.dateDue.format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
        priority: values.priority,
        checked: false,
      });
      form.resetFields();
      updateTaskList(newTaskList);
      closeModal();
    },
    [taskList, form]
  );

  const openModal = () => {
    setModalOpen(true);
  };

  const closeModal = () => {
    setModalOpen(false);
  };

  const { t } = useTranslation();

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Title>{t("tasks.tasksOverviewHeader")}</Title>
      <Row gutter={[16, 24]}>
        <Col className="gutter-row" span={24}>
          <TaskListTable tasks={taskList}></TaskListTable>
        </Col>
      </Row>
... 
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it - it seems that creating a new array and pushing the new task to it was not considered a state change (or perhaps a Table change trigger), unlike using the spread operator. The working code looks like this:

```
const addTask = (values) => {
    const newTask = {
      id: taskList[taskList.length - 1] + 1,
      slug: values.name,
      description: values.description,
      dateDue: values.dateDue.format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
      priority: values.priority,
      checked: false,
    };
    updateTaskList([...taskList, newTask]);
    closeModal();
    form.resetFields();
  };
```